# Split an X Desktop across multiple machines

Tags: xorg, display

I work with several laptops on my desk at once.  I'm currently using [X2x](https://github.com/dottedmag/x2x) to allow my mouse and keyboard to go from one machine to the next.  But what I'd really like is to have one big X desktop running across all the machines.  I'd like to be able to create any X program, and move it to display on any of the laptops, or even split between two laptops.

I know X is designed to separate display from computer, and it's possible to run remote X displays.  But can we create a single display where the left half is displayed on one machine, and the right half is displayed on another?

I think there used to be a display type of "X on X", but I can't find it now.  Would that help me find a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your looking for Distributed Multi-headed X (DMX):
http://dmx.sourceforge.net/